# Computing uncertainty in bins of experimental data

Tags: statistics, physics

I have two instruments, call them `A` and `B`, each of which records the current time each time the signal send by a transmitter, `T`, is received. The transmitter emits a signal *nearly* (but not every) second, over some time interval. Unfortunately, I have no record of how many signals were actually sent nor when each signal was sent. I have only the data from `A` and `B`.

We will assume that instrument `A` received "perfectly" (i.e. the number of signals sent will be taken to be number which were recorded by `A`, with no uncertainty). The goal is to then estimate the "efficiency" of instrument `B`, which is given by the percentage of pulses sent which `B` receives (so, our estimate will be the number received by `B` divided by the number received by `A`).

I want to look at the "efficiency" of `B` as a function of time, so I bin the data in 10-second intervals, and plot the efficiency over each interval on a graph. I now want to compute the uncertainty for each "bin"/point (i.e. add "error bars" to the graph). How can this be done?

I recall the formula being something like $1\over \sqrt{n}$ (where $n$ is the number of points in each bin), or perhaps it was $\frac{\sqrt{N - D}}{N}$ (where $N$ is the numerator (i.e. the number of signals received by `B`) and $D$ is the denominator (i.e. the number of signals received by `A`)), however I'm not sure.